# Duvida na sequencia de execução do codigo vba

Tags: vba

Olá sou novo por aqui,

tenho dois códigos, um que faz a busca da imagem por código, o qual é executado instantaneamente simulando um procv.
E uma macro que é executada na alteração da célula, para apagar a primeira imagem e não dar sobreposição na busca da segunda imagem.
Contudo parece que gera conflito e a imagem é apagada sem que a busca da nova imagem seja realizada.

PS. Os dois códigos executados individualmente funcionam perfeitamente, somente preciso que sejam executados em sequencia. Alguém consegue me ajudar?

Primeiro Código

```
Public Function getImage(ByVal sCode As String) As String

    On Error Resume Next ' Indica que no caso de erros de carregamento de imagem deve continuar executando a partir da próxima linha

    Dim sFile As String
    Dim oSheet As Worksheet
    Dim oCell As Range
    Dim oImage As Shape

    Set oCell = Application.Caller ' Célula onde a função foi chamada
    Set oSheet = oCell.Parent      ' Planilha que chamou a função
    
    

    
    ' Procura por uma imagem existente identificada pelo código (que precisa ser único!)
    Set oImage = Nothing
    For i = 1 To oSheet.Shapes.Count
        If oSheet.Shapes(i).Name = sCode Then
            Set oImage = oSheet.Shapes(i)
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i

        ' Se ainda não existir uma imagem com o código, carrega do arquivo e cria-a.
    ' A imagem já é posicionada na exata posição da célula onde a função foi chamada.

    If oImage Is Nothing Then

        sFile = "c:teste\" & sCode & ".jpg"
        Set oImage = oSheet.Shapes.AddPicture(sFile, msoCTrue, msoCTrue, oCell.Left, oCell.Top, oCell.Width, oCell.Height)

        If oImage Is Nothing Then ' Verifica se falhou o carregamento da imagem. Se falhou, adiciona a imagem genérica (com nome fixo)
            Set oImage = oSheet.Shapes.AddPicture("c:teste\inexistente.jpg", msoCTrue, msoCTrue, oCell.Left, oCell.Top, oCell.Width, oCell.Height)
        End If

        oImage.Name = sCode

    ' Caso contrário, se a imagem já existir, garante que ela se posiciona e cabe exatamente dentro da célula
    ' (apenas para o caso do usuário ter movido ou redimensionado manualmente a imagem sem querer)
    Else
        With oImage
            .Left = oCell.Left
            .Top = oCell.Top
            .Width = oCell.Width
            .Height = oCell.Height
        End With
    End If

    ' Retorna nada para a célula (afinal, esta é somente uma função de auxílio)
    getImage = ""

End Function
```

Segundo Código:

```
Sub ApagarImg1()

On Error Resume Next
Dim img As Object 'Era antes "As Shape"

For Each img In ActiveSheet.Pictures 'Era antes ".Shape"
    If Not Application.Intersect(img.TopLeftCell, ActiveSheet.Range("c5")) Is Nothing Then 'seleciona a área da imagem
        
        img.Delete
              
    End If
   
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Evite usar letras em caixa alta em frases, como no título por exemplo. https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5483/manual-de-como-n%c3%83o-fazer-perguntas/5505#5505

Comment: fiz a edição...

Answer (score 1):

Basta você fazer uma terceira função chamando essas duas na sequência que vc desejar.

Sub chamaSubFunc()
Call getimg()
Call apagaimg()
End sub

Ou ainda você pode dar o call apagaimg() no fim do bloco da sua funciona getimg, antes de encerrar ela.

Comment: Existe a (Sub apagarImg1.......apagarImg10) se eu colocar todas no final da (function) todas as imagens serão apagadas ao executar o código.
Preciso que sejam executadas separadamente.

Já realizei também uma terceira Sub chamando as duas igualmente você falou porém, a execução passa pelos dois códigos e só limpa a célula da Imagem.

Minha percepção que gera um conflito na execução por ser instantâneo, apesar de existir uma sequencia na execução.

Comment: Também tentei fazer uma Sub Delay, atrasando a execução da segunda, também não obtive sucesso...